# Replace json values by key with corresponding environment variable in bash

Tags: bash, unix

I have following json

```
{
  "NODE_ENV" : "production",
  "APP_URL":"test"
}
```

I would like to replace values of the keys if they exist on environment variables **by using only unix commands** not an external package or lib like `jq`.
For ex:

```sh
$ NODE_ENV=test
$ ./script_to_execute test.json
$ cat test.json
{
  "NODE_ENV" : "test",
  "APP_URL":"test"
}
```

This is my **script_to_execute** file

```
#!/bin/bash
for env in $(compgen -v) ; do
    sed -i 's/^\("$env":"\)[^"]*/\1${!env}/' $1
done
```

**EDIT**
After receiving answers and comments I realized that I haven't emphasize my needs clearly. I need to do this task without using external dependencies other than included in alpine distribution. My json file won't be nested and will include simple values like plain strings and numbers.

Comment: You'll want a JSON parser to reliably parse JSON. If it was me, I'd push back against the requirements.

Comment: @glennjackman it would be much easier with other tools but I would like to do it without additional packages if it is possible - and i know it is but not sure how :)

Comment: It's *possible*, but your solution will be very fragile, and you'll inevitably miss some edge cases. You don't need to reinvent this wheel. Suppose you have `VAR='some "value"'` in the environment and  your JSON object has the VAR key: your sed command can't handle the embedded quotes. Your sed command already can't handle spaces around the colon that is in your JSON file.

Comment: @glennjackman you are definitely right but values will be too simple. and sed can handle spaces with `\s`

Comment: well, good luck. Don't forget that variables do not expand within single quotes.

Answer (score 3):

This is really easy in Python:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import json
import os
import sys

olddata = json.load(sys.stdin)
newdata = {k: os.environ.get(k, v) for k, v in olddata.items()}
json.dump(newdata, sys.stdout, indent=2)
```

Use it like `./update_from_env.py < test.json > new.json; mv new.json test.json`

Comment: thanks for your answer but I have a requirement for doing it only using bash

Comment: @trd3v3lop `sed` is just as much not-Bash as Python is. Is this homework? Also, what about `jq`?

Comment: yeah but sed exists in bash by default(not sure but at least it exists on alpine). I need to do this on a CI script without additional dependencies.

Comment: No, sed does not exist "in" bash. It's just a program that exists in Alpine, and bash can run arbitrary programs.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me. I will edit the question and express my needs clearly

Answer (score 2):

Perl, uses a JSON module from CPAN:

```
perl -MJSON -0777 -lne '
    my $data = decode_json $_;
    for my $key (keys %$data) {
        $data->{$key} = $ENV{$key} if exists $ENV{$key};
    }
    print encode_json($data);
' file.json
```

or Ruby, with no external dependencies

```
ruby -rjson -e '
    data = JSON.parse(File.read(ARGV.shift))
    data.each_key {|key| data[key] = ENV[key] if ENV.has_key? key}
    puts JSON.generate(data)
' file.json
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change your mind and your *requirements* here is an example of shell script how you could do it by using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/).

```sh
#!/bin/sh
for key in `jq "keys | .[]" $1 | xargs` ; do
    eval "_TO_CHECK=\$$key" ## 
    if [ "$_TO_CHECK" ]; then
       jq ".$key=\"$_TO_CHECK\"" $1 > _temp.json && mv _temp.json $1
    fi
done
```

Comment: This looks like it won't handle special characters well.

Comment: @JosephSible this scripts works well if the value is valid for both json and environment variables.

Comment: It does not. Both environment variables and JSON strings are allowed to contain double-quotes, but the presence of one in the value of an environment variable will break your script.

Comment: @JosephSible this scripts replaces values as string, so, in order to make it fully compatible with json and environment variables there are more things to do. But for author's case this suits well.

Comment: Thanks for answering. this script works well in my case but I don't want to use external packages.